# Spring Boot - configuration not being read?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I am using `springboot 2.0.4.RELEASE` and am trying to configure database properties for my app. I added a new configuration file as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
public class DatabaseConfig 
{
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    
    public String getUserName() {
        try {
            userName = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/secrets/username.txt")).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        try {
            password = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/secrets/password.txt")).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Here's my `application.properties`

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://mno35978487001.cloud.xyz.com:14481
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

I was hoping when the application runs, `application.properties` will be able to read the user name and password from the file but that doesn't seem to happen. Any thoughts on what I am missing? Are there any better ways of reading those values and setting them dynamically?

Comment: your methods should be annotated with @Bean

Comment: @hamed both getters and setters need to be annotated?

Comment: If you are loading properties from mounted files, I can guess that your application might be running on Kubernetes. Then, there is a simpler way to mount files that will turn into environment variables injected into your application. Please, look at this article: https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/10/04/configuring-spring-boot-kubernetes-secrets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add custom property source locator.

https://source.coveo.com/2018/08/03/spring-boot-and-aws-parameter-store/

Basically, you need

1. Create your property source

```
    public class SecretStorePropertySource extends PropertySource<SecretStoreSource> {
    
        public SecretStorePropertySource(String name) {
            super(name);
        }
    
        @Override
        public Object getProperty(String name) {
            if (name.startsWith("secrets.")) {
                // converts property name into file name, 
                // e.g. secrets.username -> /secrets/username.txt
                return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/"+name.replace('.','/')+".txt")).get(0);           
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

2. Register it on start using custom environment post processor

```
    public class SecretStorePropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    
        @Override
        public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
            environment.getPropertySources()
                    .addLast(new SecretStorePropertySource("customSecretPropertySource",
                            new SecretStorePropertySource()));
        }
    }
```

3. Tell SpringBoot to use your custom environment post processor

Add to `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` file

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.mycompany.myproduct.SecretStorePropertySourceEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

4. Use `secrets.` prefix to pass property through your source

```
spring.datasource.username=${secrets.username}
spring.datasource.password=${secrets.password}
```

---

However, if you are going to provide it via file then just rename this file to `application-secrets.yml` and place on target server into `config` folder which itself is located in the same folder where application jar copied.

Now you can ask SpringBoot to load it by adding `secrets` into active profiles list.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-set-active-spring-profiles

---

Not saying I'm advising it but you also can make your code working

```
@Configuration
public class Secrets {
    @Bean("SecretUserName")
    public String getUserName() {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/secrets/username.txt")).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean("SecretUserPassword")
    public String getPassword() {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/secrets/password.txt")).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

and adding following lines to `application.yml`

```
spring.datasource.username=#{@SecretUserName}
spring.datasource.password=#{@SecretUserPassword}
```

Comment: "However, if you are going to provide it via file then just rename this file to application-secrets.yml and place on target server into config folder which itself is located in the same folder where application jar copied." - By this file do you mean the `DatabaseConfig` I have defined or are you referring to the `username`, `password` text files? My `DatabaseConfig` is already defined under `config` folder if that matters.

Comment: secrets file. Rename to `application-secrets.yml` and add here `spring.datasource.username=xxx` and  `spring.datasource.username=yyy` properties. Since its format is recognized by SpringBoot it will successfully load  if requested. Since this file will be stored on target server, secrets will not be exposed in source control system.

Comment: So the problem is that the secrets files are hosted remotely in a vault and the application container will them in `etc/secrets/*` once the app is deployed. I have to read those values somehow in my app if I am to have database access.

Comment: why vault cannot have `application-secrets.yml`? Are you sure it must be `username.txt` and `password.txt`?

Comment: Let me research on that, the way I set it up was just as a key-value pair in the vault so I didn't really create any `.txt` files but apparently that's the way we are supposed to reference them.

Comment: Anyway, 2nd part of my answer is about how to fix your original code. Though, it will not be springboot-way

Comment: I'll come back and mark that as answer once I can verify it, appreciate all the help! Right now, the deployment seems to be failing for some other reasons and someone else on the team has to look into it.

Comment: Did you mean to define a `SecretStoreSource` class as well? I was able to get it working only using `SecretStorePropertySource`

Comment: it was copy/paste error. `SecretStoreSource` meant to be `SecretStorePropertySource`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reading txt files you could make environment variables and use placeholders in your application.properties to reference them:

```
spring.datasource.username: ${USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password: ${PASSWORD}
```

You can read more about placeholders [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-placeholders-in-properties).

Comment: Are you suggesting Spring environment variables? I mean I would still need to read those files to get the values though since those files are available only after deployment.

Comment: Hey @linuxNoob, yea I was suggesting to load your username/password configuration into environment variables set by your container runtime and accessing them with ${} placeholders in your properties file.

Comment: @munnsId can you point to any resources to load username/password to environment variables?

Comment: @linuxNoob absolutely :)! [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-container-environment-variables) is a nice article explaining this with Docker container.

With [--env-file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file) you could even keep your username.txt/password.txt files.

Comment: Can I pass logic in environment variables as well? I need to read those secret files in order to get those values.